# Approximate identities on the unit disk and going beyond a power series' radius of convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, power-series, integral-kernel

Let $\left\{ a_{n}\right\} _{n\geq0}$ be a bounded sequence of complex numbers, so that the power series $f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ has a radius of convergence $\geq1$. Additionally, suppose that $f\left(0\right)\neq0$, and that $f\left(\omega\right)=0$ for some complex number $\omega$ with $0<\left|\omega\right|<1$. Let $\nu$ be a positive non-integer real number and let $g_{\nu}\left(z\right)=\left(f\left(z\right)\right)^{1/\nu}$. Since $f$ is non-vanishing at $z=0$, $g_{\nu}\left(z\right)$ has a power series expansion: $$g_{\nu}\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\left(\frac{1}{\nu}\right)z^{n}$$ with a radius of convergence $r_{\nu}\in\left(0,1\right)$. In particular, thanks to the zero of $f$ at $\omega$, we have that $r_{\nu}<\left|\omega\right|$.

Next, let: $$g_{\nu,r}\left(t\right)=\left(f\left(re^{2\pi it}\right)\right)^{1/\nu}$$

Since $f$ is holomorphic on the open unit disk, $g_{\nu,r}\in L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\right)$ for all $p\in\left[1,\infty\right]$ and all $r\in\left(0,1\right)$.

Now, let $\left\{ K_{r}\right\} _{r>0}$ be a family of good kernels / an approximate identity on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (ex: $K_{r}\left(t\right)=P_{r}\left(t\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}r^{\left|n\right|}e^{2n\pi it}$, the Poisson Kernel), and consider the integral: $$\left(K_{\rho}*g_{\nu,r}\right)\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{1}K_{\rho}\left(t-x\right)g_{\nu,r}\left(x\right)dx$$

Because of the integrability of $g_{\nu,r}$ for each $r\in\left(0,1\right)$, the approximate identity property of the $K_{\rho}$s guarantees that $\lim_{\rho\uparrow1}\left(K_{\rho}*g_{\nu,r}\right)\left(t\right)=g_{\nu,r}\left(t\right)$ for almost every $t\in\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (in particular, the limit exists for every $t$ at which $g_{\nu,r}$ is continuous). When $r<r_{\nu}$, the power series of $g_{\nu,r}$ gives us an absolutely convergent Fourier series for $g_{\nu,r}$: $$g_{\nu,r}\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\left(\frac{1}{\nu}\right)r^{n}e^{2n\pi ix},\textrm{ }\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\textrm{ }\forall\left|r\right|<r_{\nu}$$ consequently, we can compute $\left(K_{\rho}*g_{\nu,r}\right)\left(t\right)$ term-by term using this series representation, and hence (writing $e\left(t\right)=e^{2n\pi it}$): $$\left|r\right|<r_{\nu}\Rightarrow g_{\nu,r}\left(t\right)=\lim_{\rho\uparrow1}\left(K_{\rho}*g_{\nu,r}\right)\left(t\right)=\lim_{\rho\uparrow1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\left(\frac{1}{\nu}\right)r^{n}\left(K_{\rho}*e\right)\left(t\right)$$ for all $t$ at which $g_{\nu,r}$ is continuous. However, when $\left|r\right|>r_{\nu}$, the series for $g_{\nu,r}$ fails to converge, and as such, the right-most of the above equalities no longer holds. That is, if we think of the limit: $$\lim_{\rho\uparrow1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\left(\frac{1}{\nu}\right)r^{n}\left(K_{\rho}*e\right)\left(t\right)$$ as a generalization of the abel method of summing divergent series (with respect to the parameter $\rho$), while $\lim_{\rho\uparrow1}\left(K_{\rho}*g_{\nu,r}\right)\left(t\right)$ still equals $g_{\nu,r}\left(t\right)$ almost everywhere, this equality does not appear to be realizable as an abel-style summation of a divergent series.

All that being said, I have two questions:

(I) Let $r\in\left(r_{\nu},1\right)$, so that $f\left(z\right)$'s power series about $z=0$ converges for $\left|z\right|=r$, but $g_{\nu}\left(z\right)$'s power series about $z=0$ diverges for all $\left|z\right|=r$. Under these hypotheses, as discussed above, the limit $\lim_{\rho\uparrow1}\left(K_{\rho}*g_{\nu,r}\right)\left(t\right)$ exists for almost every $t$. Is there a way to express the value of the limit (when it converges to $g_{\nu,r}$) in terms of power series coefficents of $g_{\nu,r}$ (maybe expanded about some point other than $0$), or something similar? Here, case I'm most interested in is when $K_{\rho}=P_{\rho}$, the Poisson Kernel. So understanding that particular situation is paramount, though information about the more general case would also be desirable.

(II) The Parseval-Gutzmer formula establishes the identity: $$\int_{0}^{1}\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}\left(re^{2n\pi it}\right)^{n}\right|^{2}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|c_{n}\right|^{2}r^{2n}$$ for all $r\geq0$ which are less than the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}z^{n}$. For our function $f\left(z\right)$, this gives: $$\int_{0}^{1}\left|f\left(re^{2\pi it}\right)\right|^{2/\nu}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\left(\frac{1}{\nu}\right)\right|^{2}r^{2n},\textrm{ }\forall r\in\left[0,r_{\nu}\right)$$ where, recall, $r_{\nu}$ is the radius of convergence of the power series of $f^{1/\nu}\left(z\right)$ about $z=0$. Since $t\mapsto f^{1/\nu}\left(re^{2\pi it}\right)$ is bounded for all $r\in\left[0,1\right)$, however, the left-hand side of this identity exists even for $r\in\left[r_{\nu},1\right]$. Is there a way to “correct”/alter the right-hand side of the identity so as to extend it to all $r\in\left[0,1\right)$? And if so, how would one do this?